# "Hash mismatch" error after deploying an update of PWA to IIS in production

Tags: angular, service, angular5, angular-service-worker

I have a PWA written in angular5 I'm working on.
I'm using:
"@angular/cli": "1.6.0-rc.1".
"@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",

I want to notify the user of an update to the app so as to refresh the page.

1. When I run the code locally with http-server listening on the output folder, it works fine and I see the update flow and a confirmation message for the user.
2. When running the app locally in IIS with localhost, it also works fine and I see the update flow and a confirmation message for the user.
3. When running the app locally with **specific domain** (edited in host file bound to the app in IIS), it doesn't work.
4. When running the app in production it doesn't work.

In both points 3 and 4, when I say "doesn't work", I mean I get an exception message of 
**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork):**

When I try to check it on the mobile against production, I also don't see the update flow happening.

After I refresh the page again, I see the changes and the error message disappears (the update has been done)

Here's the code that does the update:

```
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';
public isUserAuthenticated = false;
constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate,
private router: Router,
private authService: AuthenticationService) {
this.isUserAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => {      
console.log('----Update available: current version is', event.current, 'available version is', event.available);
if (event.current.hash !== event.available.hash) {
const result = confirm(`----A new Version exists, do you want to update?----`);
if (result)
window.location.reload();
}
});
this.swUpdate.activated.subscribe(event => {
console.log('Update activated: old version was', event.previous, 'new version is', event.current);
});
}

ngOnInit() {
this.checkForUpdate();
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}

checkForUpdate() {
console.log('---- checkForUpdate started----');
this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate()
.then((res) => {
console.log('---- checkForUpdate completed----');
console.log(`---- res: ${res}----`);
})
.catch(err => {
console.error(err);
})
}
activateUpdate() {
console.log('---- activateUpdate started ----');
this.swUpdate.activateUpdate()
.then(() => {
console.log('---- activateUpdate completed----');        
window.location.reload();
})
.catch(err => {
console.error(err);
})
}
```

Maybe I'm missing some specific configuration for the domain I'm deploying it to in angular?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and had to manually clear my Application Cache.  Normally I would just use the clear site data button, but for some reason I am having to open the Cache Storage and right click, delete for each item.  Then redo the 'add to desktop'.

[image]

Comment: Yea, that's what had to do "to make it work". The question is why it doesn't work in a specific domain and works locally